# Tag for "error writing": produce package errors and warnings

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there a tag for questions that concerns producing errors? I am thinking of `\PackageError{package-name}{error-text}{help-text}`, `\ClassWarning{class-name}{warning-text}` and other similar ways of raising errors and warnings when writing a package. Is there a tag for this?

If not, I think it should be a tag. It might not be popular, but sometimes I find myself asking questions concerning how to produce errors and warnings for my packages.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific tag for producing errors yet. Questions about this are usually tagged with a combination of `package-writing` and `errors` and/or `warnings`. If you want you can introduce a new tag, just put a non-existing tag on your next questions and then it exists.

Comment: The "risk" of a dedicated package error tag will be misuse from users who are unfamiliar with the tag. Just look at how the biblatex tag often gets used on posts which have nothing to do with bibliographies - probably because it comes up when the user searches for tags which contain `latex` and don't read the tag description. Similarly such a new tag will be used for all kinds of questions which involve some kind of error.